# parLapply to apply user defined function to each list element in r

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am trying to `parLapply()` a function to each element of list "inputs". Each element is name of [r](/questions/tagged/r) workspace. Each workspace contains a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) with name same as workspace name. So,

```
1->loading workspace, 
2-> removing extension using strsplit() to get data.frame name, 
3->using as.name() to give it to a variable, 
4->performing inner join using merge(), 
5->rbind results of merge to a dataframe
6-> and removing unused variables from storage
```

The function I have written is below

```
library(parallel)
no_cores<-detectCores()
clust <- makeCluster(no_cores)

blockchain2009 <- data.frame()


load("blocktransact2009.RData")

inputs <- c("blockinputs1.RData","blockinputs2.RData")

parLapply(clust,inputs,process_inputs)

process_inputs <- function(i)
{
load(i)
i<-strsplit(i,"\\.")
blockinput<-as.name(i)

temp <- merge(x=blocktransact2009,y=blockinput,all.x=TRUE)
blockchain2009 <- rbind(blockchain2009,temp)
rm(temp,blockinput)
}
```

I get below, how to resolve. `parLapply()` should apply to each list element.

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>         one node produced an error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'symbol'

Comment: This is a pretty bad way of approaching this. `parLapply` does not have access to `blockchain2009`.

Comment: is that why i get error? how to resolve this